# Is there any general purpose compression library in .NET

Tags: .net, nuget, compression, image-compression

I need to compress strings, images, pdf etc..

Wondering, is there any .NET library that can handle all those?

Right now, I'm using different library for string and images..

Comment: Anything will do. Need to send it over socket.

Answer (score 0):

Images and PDF files are almost always already compressed, so no point there. If by "strings" you mean large text files, then you can use the `GZipStream` class. If by "strings" you actually mean short strings, e.g. 10's to 100's of characters, then trying to compress those individually would be mostly pointless.

Comment: Let me clarify: Large strings, app-generated PDF. All of them including images is sent over socket in to my client app, so 1 MB image would be sent as 1 MB.